# Como posso criar um banco de dados dinamico no pyhton

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlite3, pycharm

Alguem poderia me auxiliar em como criar um banco de dados dinamico, onde posso adcionar e remover itens? Na linguagem Python, se possivel com o Sqlite

Comment: Comece estudando a [documentação oficial da `sqlite3`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sqlite3.html).

Answer (score 2):

No exemplo abaixo, o banco de dados SQLite é criado no arquivo `foobar.db`, onde uma tabela chamada `tb_fruta` é criada e seus itens manipulados (inclusão, alteração e exclusão) por meio de comandos `SQL`:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('foobar.db')

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("CREATE TABLE tb_fruta ( id integer, nome text );")

c.execute("INSERT INTO tb_fruta ( id, nome ) VALUES ( 1, 'BANANA' );");
c.execute("INSERT INTO tb_fruta ( id, nome ) VALUES ( 2, 'LARANJA' );");
c.execute("INSERT INTO tb_fruta ( id, nome ) VALUES ( 3, 'MELANCIA' );");
c.execute("INSERT INTO tb_fruta ( id, nome ) VALUES ( 4, 'MACA' );");
c.execute("INSERT INTO tb_fruta ( id, nome ) VALUES ( 5, 'UVA' );");
c.execute("INSERT INTO tb_fruta ( id, nome ) VALUES ( 6, 'MORANGO' );");

c.execute("UPDATE tb_fruta SET nome = 'LIMAO' WHERE id = 2;");
c.execute("UPDATE tb_fruta SET nome = 'ABACAXI' WHERE id = 6;");

c.execute("DELETE FROM tb_fruta WHERE id = 3;");
c.execute("DELETE FROM tb_fruta WHERE nome = 'UVA';");

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Testando:

```
$ sqlite3 foobar.db 
SQLite version 3.7.17 2013-05-20 00:56:22
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> SELECT * FROM tb_fruta;
1|BANANA
2|LIMAO
4|MACA
6|ABACAXI
sqlite>
```